# jQuery responsive toggle menu works only once

Tags: jquery, css

I am not fluent in responsive and jQuery, this is for my first project into responsive, all are working fine but top menus toggles only once don't know how to solve.

My jQuery:

```
$("#pull").bind('click touchstart', function () {
        //$(".responsiveMenu, .mobile-responsive-menu").slideToggle();
        $(".responsiveMenu, .mobile-responsive-menu").toggle();
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $(".responsiveMenu, .mobile-responsive-menu").hide();
    });
```

I've created a fiddle for quick reference please look into my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/santosh_patnala/DAuN3/).

Comment: You are using same classes on different elements, thats the first issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have two elements with the class `mobile-responsive-menu`:

```
<div class="mobile-responsive-menu">
    <ul class="mobile-responsive-menu">
```

Remove that class from the div.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Dss/

Note that to get it working I am only toggling the ul (`.mobile-responsive-menu`), not the individual buttons (`.responsiveMenu`), which is overkill.